# Is there a source code editor for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, notepad++

I use notepad++ for my html and css, but unfortunately it does not have support for jQuery (which kinda surprises me 'cause it's popular and notepad++ is usually on top of things). Anbody know anything about a jQuery source code editor? each time I Google I get "online editors built with jQuery" kind of responses. Also, if you know of a plugin for notepad++ jQuery (which I can't find) that would work too

by support I mean when you go to type up a document, you can select it in the "language" bar

Comment: Well...jQuery really is just JavaScript...and I'm pretty sure Notepad++ has JS. But for custom jQ functions...idk.

Comment: Notepad++ does indeed support JavaScript. And as jQuery *is* JavaScript, that should be all you need.

Comment: I am not quite sure, if javscript support is what WebMaster is asking for. jQuery support is often considered as some kind code completion or intellisense, meaning .filter() .show() and the like are known and suggested by the editor / ide.

Comment: Define "support", because highlighting keywords isn't really support, and a text editor can't "support" a language in the first place...

Comment: https://twitter.com/BoltClock/status/63609746057465856

Comment: why is there a negative vote?

Answer (score 2):

After reading this question, I think what you are looking for is jQuery code hinting in Notepad++. I've often wondered about this myself, and a quick search didn't turn up anything useful, so I decided to have a go at adding it myself.

Personally, I think it's worked quite well. I've added code hinting for all of the jQuery methods (with a couple of exceptions, notably `live` and `die` since they are not needed since 1.7), and I've included a description of each method, all overloaded forms of each method, and a description of the arguments. See screenshot:

[image]

And [see here for more information and download link](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/11/26/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/). And for more installation information, the [User Defined Languages page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) on the Notepad++ wiki is a good palce to go.

Unfortunately, I struggled to make it work for selectors (the `:` character seems to mess it up), and I only managed to add the method names as "keywords", so they appear all the time when you type something matching (not only after a `.` for example). So I'm sure it's not perfect, and please let me know if you notice any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Aptana](http://aptana.com/)**. This program is an eclipse based IDE. It has a good javascript code completion support, but basically not support jQuery completion. To install jQuery code completion, you have to **[download](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support)** a `.sdocml` file for the jQuery source and add it to your project. Now if you start typing `$("foo").a` for example, this shows up the list with a possible methods and properties, and also shows a little documentation for the selected function.

[image: example for jquery support]

Comment: JSLint and jQuery support? Those are two different JavaScript things. How does Aptana "support" them exactly?

Comment: sorry for poor explanation. I searched for a little and completed my answer.